# Why setTabOrder didnt work at all? Loopy or single not working

Tags: python, pyqt

I tried it in simply one example but i cant figure how to do it.
I search like 2-3 hours for figure also even in QtDesigner i cant run it correctly.
I also tried with .focusProxy not working

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



class Pencere(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.icayarlar()

    def icayarlar(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Deneme")

        self.b1=QLineEdit()
        self.b2=QLineEdit()
        self.b3=QLineEdit()

        self.v_box=QHBoxLayout()


        self.v_box.addWidget(self.b1)
        self.v_box.addWidget(self.b2)
        self.v_box.addWidget(self.b3)

        self.setTabOrder(self.b1,self.b3)




        self.setLayout(self.v_box)









app=QApplication(sys.argv)

pencere=Pencere()
pencere.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i also tried this

```
self.setTabOrder(self.b1,self.b3)
self.setTabOrder(self.b3, self.b2)
self.setTabOrder(self.b2, self.b1)
```

Comment: If you run the code in a terminal or prompt, you'll see an important warning: `QWidget::setTabOrder: 'first' and 'second' must be in the same window`. That's because you're setting the tab order *before* the widgets actually become child of the same parent. Move `setLayout()` *before* `setTabOrder()`, or just do `self.v_box = QHBoxLayout(self)`. Btw, try to avoid unnecessary blank lines, and, instead, use spaces around the equal symbol used as assignment.

Comment: You are amazing. Really thank you so much for solution and explanation and for  suggestions.
When i try it in pycharm it didnt give me any error message. Just worked normally always.

Comment: IDEs are not always able to show debug messages, and when they do they are usually incomplete. It's not a bug, it's due to their nature. Whenever you get an unexpected behavior and don't get any warning, always consider running the code from a terminal or prompt. While it may not always provide the solution, it's better to be safe than sorry. Anyway, you must be always aware of object relations ("parentship"), many functions require that objects are strictly related at some level. In your code, those line edits are virtually completely independent until the layout is set (parented).

Comment: To clarify, while the documentation of QLayout says that `addItem()` (which is internally called by layouts when `addWidget()` or `addLayout()` are called) takes ownership of the item, the ownership is only about the QLayoutItem that *contains* the widget or layout. It's only when the layout is finally part of a widget (directly, or through a parent layout that is set on a widget) that the parent of the underlying widgets is finally changed. Until that moment, those widgets are virtually ***not*** part of the same window (unless they *were* child of another window).

Comment: Thank you so much again :), it really developed my perspective, not only about PyQt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run first setLayout(), then the setTabOrder().

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Pencere(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.icayarlar()
        self.show()

    def icayarlar(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Deneme")
        self.b1=QLineEdit()
        self.b2=QLineEdit()
        self.b3=QLineEdit()
        self.v_box=QHBoxLayout()
        self.v_box.addWidget(self.b1)
        self.v_box.addWidget(self.b2)
        self.v_box.addWidget(self.b3)

        # first setLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.v_box)

        # after setTabOrder()
        self.setTabOrder(self.b1,self.b3)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wid = Pencere()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While I've already explained it in my comment, it would be more helpful (and useful) for your answer (and anybody that would directly jump to answers) to *explain* why that change in the code solves the problem. Please [edit] your post and add more details, as answers that are almost only code are not as useful as they could.